# Django: detecting users coming from google adwords using Google analytics Universal Tracking

Tags: django, google-analytics, google-ads-api

By using the universal suite the utmz cookie is no longer exists.

What is the best practices today to detect users coming through cpc campaign?

I've searched online and couldn't find an answer.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the landingpage look for the query parameters - either `utm_medium=cpc` for manually tagged campaigns or `gclid` for Adwords campaigns with autotagging.

If you need the value in subsequent pages you need to store it (in a cookie or localstorage) yourself. GA does not offer a built-in mechanism to detect campaign information on subsequent pages (there is a realtime API but that's not nearly robust enough for this use case). The information is no longer available on the client side because attribution is (since the advent of the measurement protocol) done on the Google servers, hence no cookie or equivalent mechanism.